Different estimates of conditional mean parameters from OLS vs ARCH
Consider the market model for security $i$:
$$
R_{i,t}=\alpha_i + \beta_i R_{m,t} + e_{i,t}.
$$
I estimated the parameters with the OLS method.
                coef       std err      t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const          0.0219      0.040      0.548      0.584      -0.056       0.100
INDEX          1.2734      0.028     44.718      0.000       1.218       1.329

With daily frequency though, the error term shows ARCH effects, so I used GARCH(1,1) model.
garch = arch_model(Y, X, mean="LS", vol="GARCH", p=1, q=1, dist="t", rescale=False) 
results_garch = garch.fit()

The output:
                 coef   std err         t        P>|t|      95.0% Conf. Int.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Const         -0.0240  2.971e-02     -0.809      0.418 [-8.226e-02,3.418e-02]
INDEX         1.2203  4.473e-02     27.284  6.517e-164   [  1.133,  1.308]
                              Volatility Model                             
===========================================================================
                 coef    std err        t      P>|t|      95.0% Conf. Int.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
omega          0.4857      0.267      1.816  6.935e-02 [-3.847e-02,  1.010]
alpha[1]       0.1344  5.834e-02      2.304  2.123e-02  [2.007e-02,  0.249]
beta[1]        0.6634      0.155      4.275  1.913e-05    [  0.359,  0.968]

Is it normal that $\hat\beta_{\text{ARCH}}$ (the systematic risk, 1.2203) is lower than $\hat\beta_{\text{OLS}}$ (1.2734) for the same security? I thought it changed just the standard error.

The difference is a numerical issue stemming from the MLE estimation step of GARCH, as discussed nicely by Richard.

If you did sequential estimation (run OLS, obtain the residuals and then fit a GARCH model to the residuals), obviously, the point estimate of the conditional mean equation would be the same as the one from pure OLS. However, here you do simultaneous estimation of the conditional mean and the conditional variance equations.
However, the difference in estimates is small. If you look at the 95% confidence interval for INDEX from OLS ([1.218, 1.329]) and then for INDEX from GARCH ([1.133, 1.308]), you will see that the two overlap. So (informally!) the difference is within the bounds of measurement error.
